# Is there a way in .NET Core to use the .NET Framework's implementation of GetHashCode()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hash, jwt, gethashcode

I am using a JWT token's **hash** as part of a cache key, since I want to provide different values when a different token is used.

The hash code is **calculated in service written in .NET Framework**, and is given as one of the inputs to **another service** (that has the cache implementation and logic) which is **written in .NET Core.**

[Since the GetHashCode() returns different results in the two services,](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.compareinfo.gethashcode?view=netcore-3.1#:%7E:text=returns%20identical%20values.-,However%2C%20there%20is%20not%20a%20unique%20hash%20code%20value,each%20unique%20character%20span%20value.&text=same%20hash%20code.-,The%20hash%20code%20itself%20is%20not%20guaranteed%20to%20be%20stable,for%20a%20single%20version%20of%20.) is there a way to mimic the .NET Framework's hash code in the .NET Core service?

If not, is there a simple way to distinguish between two JWT tokens?

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't the `.Id` property identify a token?

Comment: The token is signed by me as well, if I have to set the JTI claim I have to provide value (which also requires changes in both services, which we prefer to avoid at the moment due to backward compatibility issues)